# GIPHY API call only returns one gif in {Object} when limit is set to 10

Tags: javascript, api

Doing this strictly in javascript (because of the course I'm enrolled in).

```
async function searchQuery(searchID){
    const myKey = "mykey" //deleted for privacy
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?api_key=${myKey}&s=${searchID}&limit=10`, 
    {mode: "cors"});
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
    }
    searchQuery().catch(function errorMessage(error){
    console.log(error);
    }) 
}
```

The returned Object is only one Gif although I set the limit=10. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What search term are you using for the `&s=` param? Could be there's only one result for that search.

Comment: Did you mean to use the translate endpoint?   I don't think that endpoint supports multiple return values.  Did you mean search instead?

Comment: @Grax32 I tried the search endpoint, it had the same result

Comment: @Gavin I ran the function with a lot of parameters, like "cats", "dogs", etc; there should be tons of results

Comment: Make sure your search param does not have a trailing carriage return in it, or any other character that invalidates the limit parameter. Perhaps try putting the limit parameter first. And make sure you try the search endpoint

Comment: @Grax32 my mistake, I was reading the documentation wrong. search endpoint requires ?q=${searchID}; I was using ?s=${searchID}.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found the fix!